# Open jquery modal dialog from controller in MVC3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

In my `_Layout.cshtml` I write javascript code, that allow me to display modal dialog on the page with form for user login when I click on link, and that is work. My problem is that I want do something like that:

I click on ActionLink, that run code from controller, i.e:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            ViewBag.PlaceID = new SelectList(db.Places, "PlaceID", "Name");
            ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserID", "FullName");
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "User");
        }
    }
```

Anyone have idea, how to change `return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "User");` code, for something that show me my modal dialog instead of opening new page for login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the click in javascript.

Your click should open the modal window, this could be a partial you return from a controller.. or just do a show hide. have the login sitting on the page already. But if you wanted to you could put a remote URL (which would be a call to your controller) in the source of the modal window.

check out this:

[ASP.Net MVC jQuery Dialog Partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807912/asp-net-mvc-jquery-dialog-partial)

Comment: My question isn't about how to load something in jquery dialog. My problem is to open this dialog if my controller finds that this needs.

Comment: Ok i see. It is possible.. but not really the way to go about it. #1 if your initial call to the controller is not done with ajax then you are making a new page request. So your page will reload. To get the modal window to open your model could have a "showModal" var passed to the view. In the view you could have some js that would run $(document).ready(function () {
       if(@showModal) then show it..
    }); But the other way would be to make the initial call with ajax... check the response.. if you need to redirect to a new view do it in the response.. otherwise show the modal.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a good approach, I will try to implement it soon.

Answer (score 0):

use an [`Ajax.ActionLink()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470331.aspx).

controller:

```
public ActionResult Login() 
{
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    return View(); //fallback for no-js
}
```

and in the view:

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Accounts", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "modal-login", OnComplete = "$('#modal-login').dialog('open');" })
```

Comment: It's still not what I need. My links must go to diffrent actions in diffrent controllers, and that actions must check to open view or modal window for login.

Comment: Well, there's always just using 2 different links.  `@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) { // link to somewhere } else { // link to login }`